# Problemas para importar o restaurar base de datos sql server 2019

Tags: sql-server

no he utilizado mucho sql server, pero recien me instale el express para revisar unas base de datos, pero tengo unos problemas ya que me enviaron un comprimido con las base de datos y al descomprimir el comprimido me aparecen los archivos de sql server sin ninguna extension o tipo de archivo y haciendo una prueba colocandole .sql se ejecutan los archivos pero el contenido me aparecen con caracteres extraños y no se entiende bien. Nose si alguien puede  darme una ayuda de que puedo hacer el que me envio las base de datos solo me comento que debo restaurar las base de datos primero,  pero lo intente y no me aparecen porque no tienen ninguna extension o tipo de formato

Comment: Y probaste restaurar la base de datos? no hay mucha info en la pregunta como para ayudarte... no importa si el archivo tiene o no extension...

Comment: es que el problema es que los archivos cuando descomprimi el comprimido me aparecen sin ninguna extension, no estoy seguro si es normal eso en sql server ya que no utilizo ese gestor de base de datos.

Comment: para hacer la prueba de restuarar lo que realice fue colocarle yo mismo el .bak pero me envio error al resturar creo que es porque no es la extension correcta

Comment: Probablemente al hacer el backup no le pusieron extensión (que es opcional). Debes intentar restaurar la base de datos, con la opción correspondiente, y escoger este archivo descomprimido.

Comment: la extension no tiene nada que ver con lo que tratas de hacer. porque entonces no agregas a la pregunta esa nueva informacion con el error que tiro?

Comment: porque no estaba seguro de cual podria ser el error. pero si me has comentado que es opcional colocarle una extesion o no. en ese caso como podria  restaurar esas base de datos sin extensiones

Comment: Puedes seguir este link que te ayudará. https://javifer2.wordpress.com/2018/09/12/restaurar-base-de-datos-desde-bak-sin-perder-nada/

Comment: Hola Javier, een caso si los archivos no tienen ninguna extion tipo .bak como podria realizarlo?

Comment: Solo coloque a los archivos el .bak y realice los pasos del link y me funciono gracias Javier

Comment: De nada @kain Como habrás observado, me ha tocado hacer muchos restores.